# Why some date Ignored when insert from DataGridView into database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Here is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ChheckOut(rakmsheek,tare5sheek,esmsa7bsheek,mablgh,hesab,esmel7sab,mla7zat,rakmkeed,tare5,rakmel3mel,segldareby,most5dm,rakm7araka,madfo3nakdan,madfo3bshikat,magmo3shikat,mgmo3nakdanwshikat,khasmelmosder,mablgh7esab,esmel3mel,addresso) VALUES ('" 
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column1"].Value + "', '" 
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column2"].Value + "','" 
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column3"].Value + "', '" 
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column4"].Value + "',' " 
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column5"].Value + "',' "
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column6"].Value + "', '" 
                            + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["Column7"].Value + "','" 
                            + maskedTextBox1.Text + "','" + maskedTextBox19.Text + "','" 
                            + maskedTextBox3.Text + "','" + maskedTextBox4.Text + "','" 
                            + maskedTextBox12.Text + "','" + maskedTextBox13.Text + "','" 
                            + maskedTextBox6.Text + "','" + maskedTextBox10.Text + "','" 
                            + maskedTextBox7.Text + "','" + maskedTextBox9.Text + "','" 
                            + maskedTextBox8.Text + "','" + maskedTextBox11.Text + "','" 
                            + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "');";
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Not full rows insert into the database I don't know why. And its random, not the same data left every time :(

Comment: What do you mean that "full rows [don't] insert into the database"?

Comment: You might be trying to insert null values into not null value columns in your table and that might be one of the reasons why not all of the data inside the grid view is being inserted. Try putting the code between a try catch block to see if any exceptions are getting thrown. and you can also run up a sql profiler to monitor if the sql statements are being run in the way you think they are.

Answer (score 0):

What does your table schema look like?  Also, what is some sample data you are trying to insert?
If the insert is succeeding, but the data stored isn't what you were expecting, it's probably not inserting null into not null.  If the only fields not showing up are datetime data types, that might be a huge clue.  Make sure you are actually trying to insert the correct datatypes.